# Azure ASR - Test Failover VM Name ,IP Address Issue

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

I have set of VMs in Azure and I am trying to setup site recovery in another region using Azure ASR using Azure portal.
We have EXPRESSROUTE integration enabled and all the VMs are joined to on premise domain.

After test failover, I noticed that the "ping  "points to the IP address of the secondary region. I thought that it is a expected behavior.

But after cleaning up the test failover, I noticed that the "ping " name still poiting to the secondary region VM (The VM was deleted after cleanup).

Due to this I am not able to connect to the primary region VM.

Could you please suggest on how to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After running the cleanup task manually, you need to [re-protect the secondary Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-failover-failback#reprotect-the-secondary-vm), so that it replicates to the primary region.